# How to send Push Notification from iOS and Swift to FireBase Cloud Messaging?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've created a Firebase project, set up push notifications for the iOS app and in the FB console. 
Sending a Push notification to the app from the FB console works.

I want to send a push notification from the iOS app to subscribers of a specific topic. However, using the FB server key for the HTTP Post authentication fails with a 401 error:

```
    {
    error =     {
        code = 401;
        message = "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.";
        status = UNAUTHENTICATED;
    }
```

Here is my code:

```
let sendUrl = URL(string:"https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/testapp-69c05/messages:send")!
var request = URLRequest(url:sendUrl)
request.httpMethod = "POST"

let serverKey = "<server key from Firebase console, Cloud Messaging>"
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = ["Content-Type":"application/json",
                               "Authorization": "key=\(serverKey)"]
request.httpBody = jsonData;

//submit the request
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
        //
}
task.resume()
```

Should this approach work, or do I have to create an OAuth 2 token with the Google API Client Library? How to do this from an iOS app?

Comment: This is *strongly not advisable*. Initiating the request requires the server key -- which should always be kept secret and secure (as per its name) in your server and putting the key on the client app is a security risk.

Comment: In theory, you might be right. However, there are already sensitive information in the app GoogleService-info.plist, allowing full access to my data in Firebase. Having a server key which could only be used to send messages would not raise the security risk much in my opinion ( I'd have downloaded it from Firebase at startup and kept it in memory anyway) And on the theory level, once I have a secure, authenticated connection to the Firebase database, why do I need to jump over another security hoop just to send a message to my own topic? Anyway, my question was whether it is possible or not

Comment: "*In theory, you might be right.*" -- This is the practice since FCM was called GCM. IMHO, choosing to ignore even a small security risk is a red flag. "*..whether it is possible or not*" -- t's possible, well at least that's when I tried it on an Android client. You're receiving a 401, either you're using the wrong server key or it's not set properly.

Comment: `key=\(serverKey)` -- Maybe the `\` is causing it?